# jQuery Toggle doesn't work properly and mixes up animations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I basically want to achieve the following:

When the user click on the link "a#showhideuser", several animations are performed:

1. .users is shown (it is a class taking up the whole screen and
   darkens it)
2. ## user1 #user2 and #user3 are displayed (just showing

   a profile picture and the user-name) They are all blending in by changing the height of the classes.

When the link is pressed again, everything should disappear again.

It should look more or less like the old Tumblr-App "New Entry"-Menu [image: Tumblr Menu]

The problem is that sometimes all this toggling works perfectly, but sometimes it doesn't.
I have observed these possibilities after clicking the link:

1. Everything works fine (both slide in and slide out again)
2. .users is displayed fine, but the other 3 DIVs actually disappear instead of sliding in (mostly happens when I clicked the link several times already) When I wait a little, all 3 DIVs appear again
3. .users is displayed fine, but the other 3 DIVs quickly appear but then disappear again. Here as well: When I wait a little, all 3 appear again

That's my code (all in the same .js-file) (UPDATED)

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.route').hide();
        $('a#showhideroute').click(function () {
            $('.route').toggle(400);
            $('a#showhideroute').toggleClass('active');
        });

        $('.frage').hide();
        $('a#showhidefrage').click(function () {
            $('.frage').toggle(400);
        });

        $('.users').hide();
        $('#user1').hide();
        $('#user2').hide();
        $('#user3').hide();
        $('a#showhideuser').click(function () {
            $('.users').fadeToggle(200);
            $('#user1').animate({height:'toggle'},200);
            $('#user2').animate({height:'toggle'},200);
            $('#user3').animate({height:'toggle'},200);
            
        }).finish(true, false);

    });
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You don't need a `$(document).ready(....` for each thing. This may affect the order which each `ready` block is executed, so you should consolidating all your code into just 1 `$(document).ready(...`

Comment: You should also replace the four different click handlers targeting the same element with a single click handler. It will make things clearer and possibly easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I've now implemented both of them... Still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're having troubles with [animation queuing](https://api.jquery.com/queue/).

I suggest adding [`.finish(true, false)`](https://api.jquery.com/finish/) before starting any new animation.  This will stop the animation in it's place without skipping to the end; the new animation will then start from where the last one got stopped.

Comment: I've added that now (in the right place?), but also followed the other suggestion to put it all in one function... Still doesn't work properly

Comment: Wrong place.  You need it directly before the `animate()` function:
`$('#user1').finish(true, false).animate({height:'toggle'},200);`
This will stop any animations currently playing or queued for `#user1` and then start the new animation.